# (No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io...)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqrCW.png)I am building an application that uses firebase and share the content of the application
The app was working fine and when I added the firebase packages I got errors:

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)

I have tried more than one method
(flutter clean)  many times
(flutter pub get) many times
(flutter run)
(reinstall app) many times
I searched for solutions but it didn't work

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
static String id = 'HomeScreen';
const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
 }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<Home> {

Future<InitializationStatus> _initGoogleMobileAds() {
return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
}


 late BannerAd _bannerAd;

 bool _isBannerAdReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
 _bannerAd = BannerAd(
  adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
  request: AdRequest(),
  size: AdSize.banner,
  listener: BannerAdListener(
    onAdLoaded: (_) {
    setState(() {
      _isBannerAdReady = true;
    });
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
     print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
     _isBannerAdReady = false;
      ad.dispose();
    },
  ),
 );

 _bannerAd.load();
 enter image description here}


 @override
 void dispose() {
  _bannerAd.dispose();
  super.dispose();
 }}
```

I added ads in same class that has _launchUrl()

```
    _launchURL() async {
    const url = 'url';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
    } else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
   }
  }
```

and _share() method also

```
         onTap: () {
           Share.share(appUrl);
              },
```

Comment: where do you use `canLaunch()`?

Comment: Please share the code that causes these exceptions.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Comment: hello, thnks for help I added ads in the same class that has a method _launchUrl()

Comment: @PeterKoltai 
@ Alex.F

Comment: If you have `url_launcher` in your `pubspec.yaml`, you have `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';` in the file where you use `canLaunch`, and your code can be compiled, it should work.

Comment: You could also try deleting `pubspec.lock` and `run flutter pub get`.

Comment: @ Peter Koltai yes i added import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Comment: have to add  permission in xml android?

Comment: i delete pubspec.lock and restart vb and still does'nt work

Comment: @PeterKoltai thnks for time i solved it

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer
I was using the `flutter_facebook_auth` package: when read doc [link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth)

When you install this plugin you need to configure the plugin on Android before run the project again . If you don't do it you will have a No implementation found error because the facebook SDK on Android throws an Exception when the configuration is not defined yet and this locks the other plugins in your project. If you don't need the plugin yet please remove or comment it.

Comment: Can you explain how to fix this?